# Security properties of an encryption scheme built from a PRP and a PRG

Tags: encryption, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-permutation

Note: This was my in-class problem last week and potentially will be on the exam tomorrow. Thus, I want to reconfirm my thoughts so that I'll be ready to face this type of question (if appear) tomorrow.

**Question:**

> Assume I have an encryption where the key is computed using a PRP $P$ and the message is computed using a PRG $G$ so that
>
> $$E(k,m) = ( P(k,r) , G(r) \oplus m )$$
>
> (also given) $k \in K = X = Y = \{0,1\}^n$ and $m \in M = \{0,1\}^{2n}$
>
> $P$ is the PRP, $G$ is the PRG, and $k$ and $m$ are the key and the message belonging to the keyspace $K$ and message space $M$ respectively, and $r$ is a random bitstring.

**My thoughts:**

First, I say that $E(k,m)$ is *not* perfectly secure because $|M| > |K|$.

Second, I can argue that $E(k,m)$ is indistinguishable because the message is generated by a PRG (assuming that the seed is independent & uniformly distributed).

Third, I claim that $E(k,m)$ is CPA-Secure too because the PRG makes the message non-deterministic.

Fourth, I think $E(k,m)$ is CCA-Secure too, right?

*Please feel free to correct me, I don't mind criticism. I think some of my thoughts are still wrong. I just want to feel ready for the exam.*

Comment: Hi, ThomasWest. I edited your question to format it a bit more nicely, but please check that I didn't introduce any mistakes while doing so. Also, could you please clarify your notation a bit? I assumed that $P$ is the PRP, $G$ is the PRG, and $k$ and $m$ are the key and the message belonging to the keyspace $K$ and message space $M$ respectively, and I would guess that $r$ is probably a random bitstring. But what are the sets $X$ and $Y$? Good luck with your exam!

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I appreciate your help, it looks nicer now. Also, yes, I'm going to add those notations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Fourth, I think $E(k,m)$ is CCA-Secure too, right?

Consider this: what if an attacker takes a valid ciphertext $E(k,m) = ( P(k,r) , G(r) \oplus m )$ and flips a bit, so that it is $P(k, r), G(r) \oplus m \oplus 1$.  What would happen if you gave this altered ciphertext to the decryptor?

Comment: I see I guess it will not make it CCA-Secure anymore. Anyway, you didn't make a comment on the rest of them, does it mean that my thoughts are correct?